# Complex Queries on Realm Android

Tags: android, realm

Can i run complex SQL queries on realm? if not how does it claim to be a replacement for SQLite?

In particular im looking for a way to sum diffrence between two colmuns in my table how is it done?

Note that im looking for an api call rather then findAll() and a loop...

Comment: That is currently not possible, so I am afraid the only option you have is `findAll()` and a loop.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry if i misunderstand your question, but I think this might be what your asking for. The sum function will calculate the sum of all numbers in a column and then you just subtract to get the difference.

```
int i = realm.where(RealmObject.class).sum("num2")-realm.where(RealmObject.class).sum("num1");
```

Comment: You are right that theortically this is the same as calculating each row but unfortunately the sums of each of the columns may go beyond bounds which makes it risky... but thanks